# Attached property not accepting default value for double

Tags: c#, wpf, attached-properties, xamlparseexception

I'm trying to use an attached property to set the left margin of a grid exclusively.
Sadly, it doesn't work. The property throws a XamlParseException "Default value type does not match type of property".

My attached property

```
public class Margin : DependencyObject
{
    #region Dependency Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Left", typeof(double), typeof(Margin),
        new PropertyMetadata(new UIPropertyMetadata(0d, OnMarginLeftChanged)));
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public static double GetLeft(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(LeftProperty);
    }
    public static void SetLeft(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(LeftProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private static void OnMarginLeftChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = obj as FrameworkElement;
        var margin = element.Margin;
        margin.Left = (double)e.NewValue;
        element.Margin = margin;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

My user Interface

```
<Window x:Class="MSPS.View.Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:MSPS.View.Controls;assembly=MSPS.View.Controls"
        xmlns:ap="clr-namespace:MSPS.View.Controls.AttachedProperties;assembly=MSPS.View.Controls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="Blue" ap:Margin.Left="20">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Margin doesn't have to be DependencyObject in order to host attached DP, object is enough:) Could you check if (double)e.NewValue is safe? double.Parse(e.NewValue.ToString()) is less elegant but more reliable. Since you are coming from XML there's not real way to provide that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You not correctly set [`PropertyMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in this case you two times create the instance of this class:

```
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Left", typeof(double), typeof(Margin),
    new PropertyMetadata(new UIPropertyMetadata(0d, OnMarginLeftChanged)));
```

Should be so:

```
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Left", typeof(double), typeof(Margin),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnMarginLeftChanged));
```

Or like this:

```
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Left", typeof(double), typeof(Margin),
    new PropertyMetadata(0d, OnMarginLeftChanged));
```

Comment: Margin.Left is double.

Comment: @user3455395: Yeah, I realized what was happening, I wrote this in my answer.

Comment: Well, that's awkward. I really didn't see that. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your problem may be in here:

```
private static void OnMarginLeftChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = obj as FrameworkElement;
    var margin = element.Margin;
    margin.Left = (double)e.NewValue;
    element.Margin = margin;
}
```

Every `FrameworkElement` has a `Margin` property that has the Framework `Thickness` type.  This is a `struct` with 4 `double` properties, `Left`, `Top`, `Right` and `Bottom`.

Instead, write it like this:

```
private static void OnMarginLeftChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = obj as FrameworkElement;
    var margin = element.Margin;
    SetLeft( margin, (double)e.NewValue );
    element.Margin = margin;
}
```

That will set your attached property.

That said, why are you using an attached property for Margins when the framework already provides a property that your existing code would work with?

Comment: In this case, it's just a typo in `UIPropertyMetadata`.

Answer (score 0):

Your attached property change handler gets called for the default value too unless I'm mistaken. Try using nullable double. I'm not sure if UIPropertyMetadata will do you any good - it has some UI specific properties, which might be an overhead in your case. Try using just default constructor without giving a specific Metadata object type.

Answer (score 0):

DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Left", typeof(double), typeof(Margin),
    new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnMarginLeftChanged));